# Google API: It's possible to authenticate on javascript and use the auth_code to get the refresh token on server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api

I need to authenticate in Google Calendar, but I can't use the server-side mode, because my page can't be refreshed, so I am using the javascript API:

```
var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"];

    gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: clientId,
        scope: SCOPES,
        immediate: false
    }, handleAuthResult);
```

As I can't refresh the page and I'll need the `refresh_token` later, I'm sending the returned auth_code by ajax to my controller, and then trying to get the `refresh_token`, this is the server side:

```
var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, "client_id", "client_secret");

IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState();

state.Callback = new Uri("myURL");
state.AccessToken = clientSecret;            

IAuthorizationState result = null;

try
{
     result = provider.ProcessUserAuthorization(auth_code, state);
}
catch (Exception) 
{

}
```

When `ProcessUserAuthorization` is called, it returns the following error:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I can't redirect the page, because the button to sync is in the end of a form, so if an user filled the form and click to authenticate, page will be redirected and he will lost every data. This is why I'm trying to do this way.